# How can get print out average pixel of a pic?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

My code is below , I want to get print out average pixel by using .averagePixels code in PIL but the output return ‘int’ object is not iterable. Anyone can help on it

```
from PIL import Image
class PixelCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, imageName):
        self.pic = Image.open(imageName)
        self.imgData = self.pic.load()
    def averagePixels(self):
        r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
        count = 0
        for x in range(self.pic.size[0]):
            for y in range(self.pic.size[1]):
                tempr,tempg,clrs = self.imgData[x,y]
                r += clrs[0]
                g += clrs[1]
                b += clrs[2]
                count += 1
        yield ((r/count)(g/count),(b/count), count)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x=[]

    pc = PixelCounter(r"C:\Users\lena-gs.png")
    print ("(red, green, blue, total_pixel_count)")
    print (list(pc.averagePixels()))
```

the output is:

```
 (red, green, blue, total_pixel_count)
 TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-121-4b7fee4299ad> in <module>()
 19     pc = PixelCounter(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\lena-gs.png")
 20     print ("(red, green, blue, total_pixel_count)")
 ---> 21     print (list(pc.averagePixels()))
 22 
 23 

 <ipython-input-121-4b7fee4299ad> in averagePixels(self)
  9         for x in range(self.pic.size[0]):
 10             for y in range(self.pic.size[1]):
 ---> 11                 tempr,tempg,clrs = self.imgData[x,y]
 12                 r += clrs[0]
 13                 g += clrs[1]

 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: @tfirinci Also there is an error at `(r/count)(g/count)`. This should not be able to run. Please make sure your code is runnable on your side, and copy exactly what you think is supposed to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `self.imgData[x, y]` is an `int` and not something that can be unpacked into three variables; that is, this is the same error you would get if you tried to do something like `a, b, c = 2`. Since your image is called `lena-gs.png`, I imagine this could be happening because you are using a grayscale image with no alpha channel:

```
In [16]: pic = Image.open('test.png')

In [17]: data = pic.load()

In [18]: data[0, 0]
Out[18]: (44, 83, 140, 255)

In [19]: pic = Image.open('test-grayscale-with-alpha.png')

In [20]: data = pic.load()

In [21]: data[0, 0]
Out[21]: (92, 255)

In [33]: pic = Image.open('test-grayscale-without-alpha.png')

In [35]: data = pic.load()

In [36]: data[0, 0]
Out[36]: 92
```

Comment: As you can see from your own example, `self.imgData[x, y]` is not an int but a tuple.

Comment: @DYZ: Fair, I used an example with an alpha channel. Let me add an example that doesn't have one.

Comment: @fuglede that is exactly what i looking for , thanks

Comment: @tfirinci: Great, if you found the answer helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Different types of images have different types of pixels. An RGB image has three* channels per pixel, but a grayscale image has only one*. You can rewrite your function in a reasonably robust way by converting pixel data to a Numpy array and using Numpy methods to calculate the means:

```
import numpy as np

pic = ... # An RGB image
picgs = ... # A grayscale image

def averagePixels(pic):
    if pic.mode=='L':
        return [np.array(pic).mean()]
    elif pic.mode=='RGB':
        pixData = np.array(pic)
        return [pixData[:,:,i].mean() for i in range(3)]
    else:
        raise Exception("Unsupported mode")

averagePixels(pic)
#[207.66529079861112, 199.11387297453703, 217.20738715277778]
averagePixels(picgs)
#[91.41583665338645]
```

*Another channel may be added to handle transparency.